# Error parsing the date/time string: Wrong time format jquery timepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, datetime-format, timepicker

I'm working with the datetimeRange from jquery timepicker but it keeps indicating that I have the wrong time format, even though it looks like everything is exactly the same. Does anyone see where the problem is? I'm not sure if it's because of the UTC at the end.

Error:

```html
Error parsing the date/time string: Wrong time format
date/time string = 2018-04-25 13:00:00 UTC
timeFormat = hh:mm:ss
dateFormat = yy-mm-dd
```

My code:

```html
        $.timepicker.datetimeRange(
          startDateTextBox,
          endDateTextBox,
          {
              dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
              timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss",
              hourMin: 9,
              hourMax: 17,
              stepHour: 1,
              stepMinute: 15,
              range: true,
              minDate: '2d',//how many days after current day
              start: {}, // start picker options
              end: {}, // end picker options
              beforeShowDay: checkDate,
              onSelect: function(selected) {
                $('#btn_book').attr('disabled', false);
              }
          }
        );
```

Thanks so much in advance!